# Overstay in South Africa

Tags: visas, legal, south-africa, overstaying

I overstayed my visa permit in 2012 and upon leaving the Republic of South Africa, I was not issued or given the form with which to pay the necessary administrative fine. How do I pay this fine, where do I pay the fine and how much would I have to pay? Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried asking the South African consulate in the country where you live?

Answer (score 1):

They may not have levied a fine.  To find out, you can try several alternatives...

1. Apply for a visa
2. Make a personal data access to the South African government
3. Instruct a South African solicitor to check it for you

All of these will work given enough time.  If you are sure a fine was levied, then you can ask for them to send you the payment details.  You can make that request through the consulate at the cognizant South African embassy.